Change the Height of a TextBox input area in WinUI 3 XAML
I've noticed when I change the height of a TextBox control in WinUI 3 XAML, the overall control height changes (not just the input area) and it will cut off bottom of the input area if I make the height less than around 56 if there is a header. For example:
        <TextBox
            x:Name="MyTextBox"
            Height="45"
            Width="Stretch"
            Header="A Text Box" />

Any way around this? It's easy to make the text box taller, but I want the input area shorter than the default.

You may change the height of header or input area after finding it with VisualTreeHelper. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78405137/winui-3-numberbox-cropping-when-width-decreased

In the DefaultTextBoxStyle,

MinHeight is set to TextControlThemeMinHeight (default: 32)
Padding is set to TextControlThemePadding (default: 10,5,6,6)

Try setting both MinHeight and Padding to 0:
<TextBox
    x:Name="MyTextBox"
    Height="45"
    MinHeight="0"
    Padding="0"
    Header="A Text Box"
    Text="ABCDE" />


If you are not familiar with DefaultTextBoxStyle, check the generic.xaml file.

When the full TexBox heigh is visible, there is a small black border at the bottom edge of the input area. The above solution does allow the text within the input area to take up less space, but it doesn't decrease the height of the text input area.

You are right. In addition to Padding, setting the MinHeigh to 0 should help.

It still is just cutting off the bottom of the input area, which makes it look inconsistent with other text boxes that have the black border at the bottom.

I added an image in my answer. Is it different on your side?

Odd. I added your text box XAML to my project, and it worked. Then the one I had started working. I have no explanation. Accepted answer.
